# Which CallingConventions to use with Reflection.Emit?

Tags: c#, .net, cil, reflection.emit

This introductory guide here says you can use `CallingConventions.Standard` for basically anything: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13337/Introduction-to-Creating-Dynamic-Types-with-Reflec

On the other hand, MSDN states this for `CallingConventions.Standard`:

> Specifies the default calling convention as determined by the common language runtime. Use this calling convention for static methods. For instance or virtual methods use HasThis.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.callingconventions

So, I assume I should listen to MSDN and only use `Standard` for static methods. But how come it works for instance methods? What's the difference?

#### Edit:

Here's some more info from experimentation:

- Constructors generated with either `HasThis` or `Standard` seem to always produce methods that reflect to `Standard`.
- Instance methods generated with `HasThis` reflect to `HasThis` and those generated with `Standard` reflect to `Standard|HasThis`.
- Instance methods defined by "static" code compilation reflect to `Standard|HasThis`.

So the conclusion is I should probably always use `Standard` after all? Still don't see any difference, to be honest, since both ways work.

Comment: I would *guess* that the main difference here is how nulls are handled and whether polymorphism works, and whether the reflection API counts arg0 as a parameter or not. Have you tried to see what happens if you invoke it against a null instance?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Did you mean to try invoking static methods against a null instance? But static methods aren't in question; they should clearly be generated with CallingConventions.Standard.

Comment: no; I'm saying: make a delegate to the instance method and call it with a null target. With the wrong calling convention, this might work - with "this" being null.

Comment: @MarcGravell Now I get it. Tried it and it complains with a TargetException. It wants a target for a non-static method. So it seems to work either way.

Comment: @relatively_random - I suspect the exact behavior is going to depend on whether the method is invoked with call versus callvirt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Standard when defining a static method.

Use Standard | HasThis when defining an instance method.

Standard basically tells .NET to use CLR Fastcall, and HasThis tells the compiler to pass a hidden this* in the first parameter.

Comment: That just isn't necessary, MethodBuilder is smart enough to add HasThis for an instance method by itself.  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/methodbuilder.cs,130

Comment: @HansPassant - If people followed the above answer, that guard code in the implementation you linked would not be necessary.  Just sayin.  +1 though for linking the implementation details.